# How can I determine the SATA channel for a given disk?

Tags: c#, .net, disk, hard-drive, sata

Using `DISKPART` command line utility, I can get something called a "Location path" which appears to give me what I need, you can view this by using the command `detail disk` after selecting one of your disks in `diskpart`.

It appears I can get this information programatically via this class: [MSFT_Disk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh830493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I am unsure about how to get an instance of this class.  I have a few examples of using a `ManagementObjectSearcher` for `WMI` classes but that method is not working for me, I am also unsure of `MSFT_Disk`'s availability in Windows 7 as the page mentions that this is for Windows 8.

Does anyone know of a good way to get SATA channel information or the "location path" of a disk?

Comment: You'll probably have to use [VDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Can't find much on how to using it from .NET but I did find [this](http://esotericalstuff.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/vds-activities-under-c-2/) which seems to go through doing some tasks.  You may be able to PInvoke your way through it as well.

Comment: Have you thought about enumerating `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IDE\device\id:LocationInformation`? It contains information like this **Channel 4, Target 0, Lun 0**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not require Windows 8, I believe WMI is the way to go:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace DiskScanPOC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var managementScope = new ManagementScope();

            //get disk drives
            var query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query);
            var oReturnCollection = searcher.Get();

            //List all properties available, in case the below isn't what you want.
            var colList = oReturnCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
            foreach (var property in colList.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} = {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
            }

            //loop through found drives and write out info
            foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : " + oReturn["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Target Id: " + oReturn["SCSITargetId"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Port: " + oReturn["SCSIPort"]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't crack open my case to verify the SATA port numbers, but the above app looks like it gives reasonable results on my machine with 3 SATA hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the location path, [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx) is the function you're looking for. Set the property value to `SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION`.

I'm assuming you already know how to enumerate devices to get the `DeviceInfoSet` and `DeviceInfoData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Management;

namespace Hard_Disk_Interface
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WqlObjectQuery q = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_IDEController");
            ManagementObjectSearcher res = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
            lblHDDChanels.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (ManagementObject o in res.Get())
            {
                string Caption = o["Caption"].ToString();

                lblHDDChanels.Text += Caption + "\n\n";
                if (Caption.Contains("Serial"))
                {
                    lblInterface.Text = "S-ATA";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is demo...]

Note: First Add the reference of System.Management.dll of .net freamwork 4.0